# Mock react-native-appearance locally with jest

Tags: react-native, expo, ts-jest

I'm trying to implement test for my  component that adapt to the light/dark mode using react-native-appearance.

As the most of my others component use this Text component, i've mocked the module globally using setupFiles :

```
import * as mocking from "react-native-appearance/src/mock";

jest.mock('react-native-appearance', () => mocking);
```

But would like to test, only for my Text component the dark mode so i tried something like :

```
const props: Props = {children: "Test", primary: true};

jest.unmock('react-native-appearance')

const mock = jest.fn();

jest.mock('react-native-appearance', () => ({
    useColorScheme: mock
}))

describe('<Text>', () => {
    describe('Themes', () => {
        it('Renders correctly in light theme', () => {
            const tree = create(<Text {...props}/>)

            expect(tree.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot();
        })

        it('Renders correctly in dark theme', () => {
            mock.mockReturnValue('dark');
            const tree = create(<Text {...props}/>)

            expect(tree.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot();
        })
    });
})
```

But this error occured :

> TypeError: (0 , _reactNativeAppearance.useColorScheme) is not a
> function

Is something i'm doing wrong ?
Note that i'm using typescript.

Answer (score 2):

Jest automatically hoists the import methods to the top of the file. This is what ensures that the mocks will override the default imports. https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#using-with-es-module-imports

This means that your mocked module will not have access to the `mock` variable.

What you could do instead here is to mock the module, import the mocked function, and run your assertions against that imported module.

```
import { useColorScheme } from "react-native-appearance";

jest.mock("react-native-appearance", () => ({
  useColorScheme: jest.fn(),
}));

describe("test", () => {
  it("renders correctly", () => {
    useColorScheme.mockReturnValueOnce('dark');

    renderer.create(<App />);

    expect(useColorScheme).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

Comment: Right, but to mock the return value with `.mockReturnValueOnce('dark')` of the module, I need to access that jest.fn() function

Comment: You can set either `mockReturnValueOnce` or `mockImplementation` on the mocked function so that it returns the value you want. Just updated the answer to include this.