# Mocking react-native Appearance with Jest

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, appearance

I am trying to test (with **Jest**) an app's theme adapting to the phone system's theme. I am handling theses changes with the [`Appearance.getColorScheme()`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/appearance) helper from **react-native**.

If I am doing a simple test I have this error : `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getColorScheme' of undefined` in my app, because when the app is running in the Jest env it can't access the native `Appearance` data.

This is why I'm trying to mock the `getColorScheme()` fn from the `Appearance` helper to simply return `'light'`.
I've tried multiple solutions like the one in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66350960/mock-react-native-appearance-locally-with-jest) which was based on a different lib, not the **react-native** sub-module.

I've tried to use the `mockComponent` fn provided by `react-native`, then import the next snippet in my test :

```js
// test/__mocks__/Appearance.js
import mockComponent from 'react-native/jest/mockComponent';

mockComponent('Appearance', {
    getColorScheme: () => { return 'light' }
})
```

I get this error `Cannot find module 'Appearance' from 'mockComponent.js'`.

I've tried this too, I think this is a wrong approach because it might mock **react-native** completely and it doesn't work :

```js
// test/test.js
// Before the tests
import { Appearance } from 'react-native';
jest.mock('react-native', () => ({
    Appearance: {
        useColorScheme: jest.fn(),
    }
}));

// And at the beginning of my test :
Appearance.useColorScheme.mockReturnValueOnce('dark');
```

Then I have this error `TypeError: (0 , _reactNative.requireNativeComponent) is not a function`.

I've seen multiple solutions to mock an entire module, `Date` or other methods found in `window` for the web env. But I'm stuck to mock this particular sub-module from **react-native**.